# ion-scroll scroll bar not displaying in android

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a div with a fixed height. Scroll bar displaying in a browser but not displaying on an Android phone.

```html
<ion-scroll style="height:300px;" scrollbar-y='true'>
  //content
</ion-scroll>
```

Comment: Because the height of your device screen is higher than the height of your div maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following css for ion-scroll and **remove** the **inline css** from html page.

```
ion-scroll {
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 300px;

}
```